# QueryParameter on POST

Tags: angular, http, post, angular2-observables

I'm using Angular2/4 to build an web app.

I need to send the object to the rest api using query parameters.
My endpoint will only accept an object through the url like this:

```
localhost:8080/api/node?type=bills&quantity=2
```

my service currently its like this:

```
addInstance(instance: Instance) {
  const params = {
    type: instance.type,
    quantity: instance.quantity
  };
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, params, {headers: this.headers}) 
  .map(res => {
    return res.json();
  });
}
```

But it's not working and in the console log says there's no object passing in the url. How can i provide a correct call to the API?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean exactly? Are you sure the server expects a POST request? Do you get any error message? If yes, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently sending body parameters, not url parameters, and your endpoint is expecting url parameters. You can, however, construct url params in angular using [URLSearchParams](https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams)

Try:

```
addInstance(instance: Instance) {
   const params = new URLSearchParams();
   params.set('type', instance.type);
   params.set('quantity', instance.quantity);

   return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body?, {params: params}  )
      .map(res => {
         return res.json();
      });
}
```

You can also just construct the url directly using string concatenation.

Although, since this is a post request you should figure out with your api endpoint what the body of the request should be since typically a post request contains one. Otherwise you should change the api endpoint to make this a get request instead. Or make the api endpoint expect body parameters instead of url parameters.

Comment: is there no way that when the http.post execute the params this could be set in the url?